# Ideal Rx Power range for Cisco 7613 controllers and interface status if not in the ideal power range

Tags: cisco

I observed Rx power out of range in 4 controllers of CISCO 7600 router as given below-

The Transceiver in slot 3 subslot 0 port 0 is enabled.
Transceiver Rx optical power              = -1.8 dBm

Similarly, for the below 3 controllers-
Transceiver Rx optical power              = -4.5 dBm
Transceiver Rx optical power              = -3.3 dBm
Transceiver Rx optical power              = -37.0 dBm

My Questions:

1. What is the ideal Rx Power range for subslots of cisco7613 routers? Please give the link of Cisco Data sheet for that.
2. If the Rx power is out of range, the interface status should be shown as up/up or down/down or up/down?  Please share the Cisco document link also.

Kindly help me in getting these answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the specific line card and port type in use?  There are literally a dozen or more potential answers here.

Comment: SPA-1CHSTM1/OC3V2 is the SPA. Please try to answer the 2nd question. Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the ideal Rx Power range for subslots of cisco7613 routers? Please give the link of Cisco Data sheet for that.

You can't base healthy operating parameters based on the router/switch model.  Optical transceivers have operating parameters set by the transceiver manufacturer in an MSA (Multi-source Agreement).  These include things like tranmission power, receive power, max temperature, etc.

For the SPA-1CHSTM1/OC3V2, you can view the specific items you're looking for in Table 2 of the [data sheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/shared-port-adapters-spa-interface-processors/product_data_sheet0900aecd80350c53.html).  Ultimately, what happens in your network is going to depend upon the distance between the devices you're connecting, the fiber type, and the transceiver type.

Also note that the minimum and maximum operating ranges specified, **do not** guarantee that things *will work* if it falls within that range, only that it *can work*.

> If the Rx power is out of range, the interface status should be shown as up/up or down/down or up/down? Please share the Cisco document link also.

SONET requires the framing to be "negotiated", so your optical connectivity would need to be good on both ends in order for the link to be up/up.